# MSMQ MessageQueueException For a short while after startup

Tags: .net, vb.net, msmq

I've got a multi-user planning application where a client sends msmq messages containing their changes to a server application, which processes them, calculates stock/time shortages, and then messages all the connected clients to update their data to show the changes.

This is working pretty well except for one exception that keeps bugging me.

This basically only happens on a few of our faster PC's (with SSD, I7, ...) right after start-up.

```
ExceptionInformation: System.Messaging.MessageQueueException
Stack:
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue+MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32, Int32, MQPROPS, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*, ReceiveCallback, System.Messaging.Interop.CursorHandle, IntPtr)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(System.TimeSpan, Int32, System.Messaging.Interop.CursorHandle, System.Messaging.MessagePropertyFilter, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransaction, System.Messaging.MessageQueueTransactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
   at Europlanner_.MSMQHandler.ReceiveMessage()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

If they open the application a minute or so after boot the error doesn't appear. So although this really isn't a game-breaking bug, I'd like to fix it.

I've done some searches for the exception and I'm guessing it has something to do with permissions, but find it strange that it only happens shortly after boot.

For testing purposes I've tried setting the permissions on the queue so that Everyone and Anonymous Log-on have full control. But that doesn't seem to help.

The machines are all in the same domain, and the queue is on one of our servers in the domain.

The code where the exception occurs is the following:

```
Private Sub ReceiveMessage()
    While KeepReading
        Dim MSG As Message = ClientQue.Receive()
        If Not DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, MSG.SentTime, Now) >= 1 Then
            HandleMessage(MSG)
        Else : DebugHandler.WriteLine(DebugTypes.Network, "Removed MSMQ message due to age. (Older than 1 minute") : End If
        LastServerCommunication = 0
    End While
End Sub
```

My own machine is a little older and slower than the machines of the users, and I personally can't seem to reproduce the bug on my own machine. The time-frame during which I can use a  user's machine to test is limited.

Does anyone happen to have an idea as to what is causing this exception?

If I need to post any additional information, just ask.

Thanks for your attention.

Edit to answer Kjell-Åke's question:

I use this little function to check whether the service is started or not:

```
Private Function QueueServiceStarted() As Boolean
    Dim Services As List(Of ServiceController) = ServiceController.GetServices().ToList
    Dim MSMQueue As ServiceController = Services.Find(Function(o) o.ServiceName = "MSMQ")
    If Not MSMQueue Is Nothing Then If MSMQueue.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then Return True
    Return False
End Function
```

Edit to add the exception message:

```
"Unable to establish connection with Active Directory Domain Services. Verify that   there are sufficient permissions to perform this operation."
```

Edit: Adding some more info

The application seems to work after the following event in the windows logs.

```
"The Message Queuing service is online with Active Directory and fully operational."
```

So basically I'm guessing the question changes to: Why does it take so long for that to happen on our faster PCs.

Comment: What errorcode do you get in the exception? Could it be that the MSMQ service hasn't started yet?

Comment: @Kjell-Åke Gafvelin The service is started. I've got a small function that runs the check as soon as the application starts. I've added the code for that to the top post.

Comment: You do have to answer Kjell, we can't help you if you don't post the exception's Message and MessageQueueErrorCode

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry for the late answer. We've had an internet outage on friday. And I was unable to do any tests yesterday. The exception's message seems to be (translated from dutch) "Unable to establish connection with Active Directory. Verify that there are sufficient permissions to perform this operation.". As mentioned earlier, after about one or two minutes the application functions without any problems. It's just right after boot that this error seems to pop up. Also doesn't seem to be happening on our slower pc's.

Comment: Hmm, you don't see a connection with "We've had an internet outage"?  Talk to you LAN admin about this.

Comment: @HansPassant Small company, I happen to be the LAN admin too, together with my colleague. Internet outage was due to road workers breaking a cable somewhere in the street. Anyways the error happens every time the users reboot and keeps happening up until 2 minutes after their reboot when the above mentioned event is logged in their event logs. Strangely I've checked a few PC's and in the event log I can see 2 MSMQ events, One saying the service is started, and the other saying the "service is online with active directory". On every user these seem to be exactly 2 minutes appart, to the second.

Comment: Do you have different versions of Windows on the slower and faster computers? On my Windows 8 the MSMQ service restarts after 2 minutes if it fails to start on the first attempt.

Comment: @Kjell-ÅkeGafvelin They're all using the same Windows 7 X64. No difference there. Prety much the only difference is that the faster ones have a SSD.

Comment: So maybe Active Directory does require a specific time to be ready, and the SSD pcs finish the whole bootup startup jobs too fast. Maybe there is a windows update for this, if those are new machines and not updated to the state of hte other machines. As workaround you may add a check if the connection is ready, and maybe encapsulate all methods in a try..catch block, to assure an error wil not stop the whole program

Comment: @Amegon Had already considered the updates but that didn't change anything. So basically I ended up encapuslating the methods in a try/catch as you suggested, along with telling the people to grab a cup of coffee while their computer is booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem, end I ended up using an event log trigger and waiting for the MSMQ to get its handshake with the ad server.

I just abhorred the thought of just thrashing with try / catch / sleep cycle untill it came up. 
It might be a bit too complex just to fix it, but I found it worth it.

That way you can structure your code to diffrentiate between startup errors on the client machine and that the MSMQ is just waiting for the AD server.

[Message Queuing Active Directory Operation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773641%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Subscribe to Events in an Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202.aspx)

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't checked back in a while. This is indeed the solution we came to aswell. Seems like the most clean and reliable way to work around this problem.